# Rails Devise Collection Route Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I have searched and cannot get the following to work.

I am trying to add a collection route as shown in the example "blog" snippets below. 
As occurs with the index route, I would like to have an archive route that presents a view of the archived blog entries when users are not logged into the application. The blog "index" route works as expected, when a user is not logged in, an index is presented. Unfortunately, the archive route results in the error listed below when the user **is not logged in**. When the user **is logged in** the archive route works as expected, presenting a listing of the archived blog entries.

I would like to have the same behavior for the "archive" route as with the index route when users are not logged into the application. How do I configure this in devise?

Thank you in advance.

#### excerpt from routes.rb

```
resources :blogs do
  collection do
    get 'archive'
  end
end
```

#### excerpt from blogs_controller.rb

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index, :archive] # Devise
  ...
```

#### url request

```
http://myexample.com/blogs/archive?blog_id=1
```

#### resulting error

```
Access denied on archive Blog(id: integer, name: string, ...
Redirected to http://myexample.com/
```

Comment: are you using any authorization gem like cancan ?

Comment: Yes, cancan. I will check that aspect since I thought that was setup correctly.

Comment: I recommend instead of updating question, write answer and accept it so that others can learn from it. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Anil.

in my Ability.rb for CanCan, I had to put the following line into the default case of the user initializer. Originally it only had the read option, which I thought would encase the archive also. I had to add the archive option.

else 
  can :read, [Blog]
  can :archive, [Blog]